# Infinite loop on method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method:

```
private int calculate_min(Int32 from, Int32 to)
{
    string minuti = "0";
    long result = (Convert.ToInt32(to) - Convert.ToInt32(from));

    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(result);
    double minutes = ts.TotalMinutes;
    minuti = Convert.ToString(minutes);
    return Convert.ToInt32(minuti);
}
```

and I call it with

```
string TxtCausale = calculate_min(Convert.ToInt32(Controllo_2_Secondi),
                                  Convert.ToInt32(Controllo_1_Secondi)).ToString();
```

but it goes in error:

> Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

[image]

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
```

_HResult=-2147023895

The error is on this line `'dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1);'`

What's wrong?

Comment: `from` and `to` are already of type `int`. Why are you trying to parse them?

Comment: Are you sure the infinite loop is located there? There is no recursion no loop to be found.

Comment: @  Yuval Itzchakov - You're all right, now I fix it and I let you.

Comment: Your code has no recursion in it. It must be at another part of your application

Comment: I've inserted an img file about my question

Comment: click "Copy exception detail to the clipboard" and paste what it gave you in to your question as a edit. Make sure to put it inside a code section (highlight and press the `{ }` on the toolbar of the text editor) to format it properly. You should try and remember to do this with any question you post here and you have a error like that.

Comment: What is `Controllo_2_Secondi`? Is that a property that also sets the datetime picker value?

Comment: I' updated my question with wxceptio details from clipboard.

Comment: It should have included the call stack, you need to look at that to see what the loop is.

Comment: @ Martin Smith: 'Controllo_2_Secondi' is a double type that will store info from method

Comment: What is the call stack when you hit this error then?

Comment: '> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.Value.set(System.DateTime value) Unknown' this is the call stack error

Comment: Show us the declaration of `Controllo_2_Secondi`.

Comment: 'Controllo_2_Secondi = (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Text) - date).TotalSeconds;' the DateTimePicker controls is in custom format and display the time in format HH:mm, is important this info?

Comment: That is an assignment to `Controllo_2_Secondi `  - it isn't the definition of it.

Comment: yes is an assignment

Comment: I've updated my qyestion, the error is in ''dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1);' 
'

Answer (score 2):

**Psychic Debugging ACTIVATE!**

I suspect that the OP is trying to do Two Way Binding.

- When Control A changes, update Control B (via a property)
- When Control B changes, update Control A

The simplest solution is to do the following check.

```
public double Controllo_2_Secondi
{
    get
    {...}
    set
    {
        if (Controllo_2_Secondi == value) return;
        //Your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing a problem with

```
dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1);
```

You add a day to dateTimePicker2.Value and in turn ValueChanged is fired
Then some where in that chain you add a day and fire off another ValueChanged
Put a debug on that line and I suspect you will see it called many times

You need to post the code that actually throwing the error.  There is no indication the code you posted at the top of the question is related to the error.

Comment: the 'dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1);' is inside  'dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged' properties. Datetimepicker2 alter day insiede it and will be reflect on control

Comment: @GianniGiordano And you are not seeing a problem with that?  You are going to continue to get voted down.  Run debug on ValueChanged and post the code that is failing (not some unrelated code  block above the error).  Show some effort.

Comment: I don t know because The code hang in this code line. The debug underline this line and Coke show me this error message . The code that is called is only this two line. May be that the datetepicker is inside his properties? And can't reflect himself?

Comment: You don't know how to post the code that is failing?  You don't know how to debug.  SO can't help you.  Show some effort.   Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks for your support frisbee!!